# How do I disable\stop or enable\start Sharepoint 2010 on my Windows 7 development machine

Tags: development, installation, configuration

I used the SharePoint 2010 Easy Setup Script to setup my Windows 7 machine for Sharepoint Development. However, I don't want the Sharepoint services hogging up CPU in the background when I'm doing other things and not actively developing for Sharepoint. How can I turn Sharepoint services on and off when I need them?

e.g. I don't want Sharepoint services starting up when I'm booting up Windows 7 - I'd rather only turn it all on when I'm actually ready to do sharepoint development etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the scripts for quickly stop and start SharePoint 2010 instance. The stops all the SharePoint windows services as well as the SQL Server instance.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emberger/archive/2009/11/16/stop-and-go-with-sharepoint-2010-on-your-workstation.aspx and the update http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emberger/archive/2010/06/02/improved-start-amp-stop-local-sharepoint-2010-scripts.aspx

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Stuart, I will consider it in the future but in that particular case the articles linked provides the requested solution and I can't add something useful myself to the subject discussed. All I can do is to explain shortly what they give. I'll do the update.

Answer (score 3):

I use SharePoint 2010 Service Manager to stop and start the SharePoint services:

[CodePlex: SharePoint 2010 Service Manager](http://sharepointserviceman.codeplex.com/)

There's even a button at the bottom to prevent SharePoint from starting on boot.